# Create JavaScript object from swaped key and value ES6 Map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have this ES6 map:

```js
Map(6) {"Coratia" => 1, "Korea" =>, "Norway" => 2, "Munich" => 1, "Austrlia" => 1, ...}
```

I'd like to swap the key and values to make it like this:

```js
 {1 => "Coratia", 1 => "Korea", 2 => "Norway", 1 => "Munich", 1 => "Australia", ...}
```

Comment: A map should not have multiple values for the same key like that unless you're hoping for a Map of string, array... in which case you could have something like `{1: ["cortia", "Korea", "Munich", "Australia"...], 2: "Norway"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have one solution that uses the idea mentioned by **CodyKnapp**. It uses [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to generate the `value->key` reverse `Map`.

```js
let myMap = new Map([
   ["Cortia", 1],
   ["Korea", 1],
   ["Norway", 2]
]);

// Generate the reverse Map.

let res = [...myMap.entries()].reduce((acc, [k, v]) =>
{
    acc.has(v) ? acc.set(v, acc.get(v).concat(k)) : acc.set(v, [k]);
    return acc;
}, new Map());

// Log the new generated Map.

res.forEach((v, k) => console.log(`${k} => ${v}`));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

**Note**, as mentioned in the commentaries, that you can't have a `Map` that will duplicate the same `key` for multiple different `values`.

Answer (score 1):

ES6 Map when converted into an array looks like so:

> ```
>  [[key, value], [key, value], [key, value],...]
> ```

A two dimensional array.

**Demo Outline**

- Assuming that we have a Map with keys and values, make a new empty Map.
- Iterate through the full Map with `for...of` loop
- On each iteration `.get()` the key/value then assign the value as key and the key as value to the empty Map.
- The console does not reveal itself by normal means in order to display its content it must iterate through each key/value pair and log them.

```js
let x2D = new Map([
  ['a', 1],
  ['b', 2],
  ['c', 3],
  ['d', 4],
  ['e', 5]
]);

let d2X = new Map();

for (let [key, value] of x2D) {
  let v = x2D.get(key);
  d2X.set(v, key);
}

for (let [k, v] of d2X) {
  console.log('[' + k + ', ' + v + ']');
}
```