# Swapping key with value

Tags: javascript, object, key-value

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm trying to swap a single key with it's value. But the delete operator doesn't seem to be actually deleting the part. I'm probably doing this an inefficient way but please explain why delete is working but not? And how to add that swapped value back. Thanks in advance.

```
function swapKeyAndValue(obj,key)
{
  for(let x of Object.keys(obj))
  {
    if (x == key){
      console.log(obj);
      let tempkey = x; //where tempkey is the key: name
      let tempval = obj[x]; //where tempval is  value:ellie
      delete obj.x;
      console.log(obj.x); //outputs undefined
      console.log(obj); //outputs the obj with the deleted value?
      console.log(obj.x); //outputs undefined
      obj.tempkey=tempval;
      //console.log(obj);
    }

  }
}
var instructor = { name: 'Elie', job: 'Instructor' };
swapKeyAndValue(instructor, 'name');
// {Elie: 'name', job: "Instructor"}
```

Comment: i think this can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55428041/how-to-swap-key-and-value-in-javascript-map

Comment: Just in case, ***immutable approach*** makes more sense, there is [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60835334/11299053)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to use Object.keys for swapping one key value .You can use bracket notation [ ] for this.

```js
function swapKeyAndValue(obj,key)
{
  let value=obj[key]
  obj[value]=key;
  delete obj[key];
  console.log(obj);
}
var instructor = { name: 'Elie', job: 'Instructor' };
swapKeyAndValue(instructor, 'name');
// {Elie: 'name', job: "Instructor"}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Immutable approach:

---

If that's not required implicitly, I'd avoid mutating your source object.

Instead,

- you may [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) your source object into target key and the `...rest` of keys
- and then simply return shallow copy of your source object with target key/value swapped:

```js
const instructor = { name: 'Elie', job: 'Instructor' },

      swapKeyAndValue = (obj,key) => {
        const {[key]:k, ...rest} = obj
        return {...rest, [obj[key]]: key}
     }
               
console.log(swapKeyAndValue(instructor, 'name'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) like this:

```js
const instructor = { name: 'Elie', job: 'Instructor' };

const reversed = Object.entries(instructor)
  .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({
    ...acc,
    [value]: key
  }), {});

console.log(reversed);
```

Or plain old JS:

```js
var instructor = { name: 'Elie', job: 'Instructor' };

var reversed = {}

for(var key in instructor) {
  reversed[instructor[key]] = key;
}

console.log(reversed);
```